# Using forms in buttons within button groups - Bootstrap and Flask

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a small web application using Flask, SQLAlchemy and Bootstrap. One of the options for the user is to change/delete a row from the database, which is shown in a table. I got the delete part working with a form in a single button, but I don't know how to do it when that button is inside a button group.

If I do it like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-warning">change</button>
    <form action="{{ url_for('del_component') }}" method=post class=del-component>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">
            <input type=hidden value="{{ component.id }}" name=component_to_delete>delete</input>
        </button>                            
    </form>
</div>
```

the delete button works, but it's not in the group anymore:

[image]

So I tried this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-warning">change</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">
        <form action="{{ url_for('del_component') }}" method=post class=del-component>
            <input type=hidden value="{{ component.id }}" name=component_to_delete>delete</input>
        </form>
    </button>                            
</div>
```

and now the button group looks nice, but clicking the delete button won't do anything.

I'm thinking it's a simple fix, but it got me stumped. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you need some CSS to change how forms are styled.

Comment: Maybe, but how would I do that? It didn't strike me as a matter of styling, just that for some reason the Python code doesn't "see" the form inside the button.

Comment: The presentation has nothing to do with Python. It's all caused by Bootstrap and other CSS (as applied to your HTML). You'll need to include CSS that styles the forms and buttons however you want them to appear.

Comment: ok, I see your point now. I suppose I can do some css on my own to mimic bootstrap's button groups , but I would still like to know how to make it work with button groups.